# Why can't conda find pip installed module in prefix (within conda evironment)

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I used pip to install the Resource module to the default conda environment on my laptop: (C:\Users\my_username\Anaconda2). I think it is called root. I installed pip to the conda environment and so I'm 90% sure the resource was installed within the environment. And indeed running `conda list` shows that the package is listed within the environment. Here is a section of the output:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\conna\Anaconda2:
#
qtpy                      1.2.1                    py27_0
requests                  2.14.2                   py27_0
Resource                  0.2.0                     <pip>
rope                      0.9.4                    py27_1
ruamel_yaml               0.11.14                  py27_1
scandir                   1.5                      py27_0
scikit-image              0.13.0              np112py27_0
```

However when I run

```
conda update Resource
```

I get the following error:

```
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
prefix: C:\Users\conna\Anaconda2
package name: Resource
```

How is it possible that `conda list` shows the module is present but `conda update` can't see them? I also noticed that `conda update` doesn't recognize any packages with `<pip>`. What is happening?

Comment: Conda and pip don't interfere each other.

Comment: Conda cannot update packages installed by pip. That is what is happening. You should avoid using pip in conda for this reason, among others, unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265533/does-conda-update-packages-from-pypi-installed-using-pip-install

Answer (score 2):

`conda` only manages the packages that are installed using a `conda` command. If you installed a package with `pip` (or using `python setup.py install` or `develop`) it will show up with `conda list` (because that shows all packages no matter how they were installed) but `conda` won't manage that package. Simply because it doesn't know how!

So if you installed a package with `pip` you also need to upgrade/update it with `pip`:

```
pip install [package_name] --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
pip install Resource --upgrade
```