# conda equivalent of pip install

Tags: python, pip, conda, miniconda

If I have a directory with `setup.py`, in `pip`, I can `pip install .` in the directory to install the package.

What if I am using `conda`?

`conda install .` makes `conda` to find a package named dot.

Comment: Are you looking to simply install the package, or do you wish for your package to be available _as_ a `conda` package? That is, are you creating something, installling something from somewhere else, or ...?

Comment: @ChrisLarson I want to just install a package, and I happen to hear that it is better not to mix ``conda`` and ``pip``. The package is not available in ``conda`` but only available by source code.

Comment: `conda` itself recommends you use pip for non-`conda` packages. See both of the answers below for correct usage of `pip` in `conda`. Note that in my answer, I point out that this is the official, recommended and best practice way to handle non-`conda` packages.

Comment: Although `conda install .` fails, I happen to find that `conda install conda-4.6.3-py37_0.tar.bz2` works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`conda` packages are a different structure than standard python packaging. As a result, **the official, recommended and best-practice** approach is to use `conda` to install `pip` within an activated `conda` environment, and use that to install standard packages:

```
conda install pip
```

**NOTE**: You want to use `conda` packages whenever they're available, as they have more features within a `conda` environment than non-`conda` packages.

`conda install pip` will install pip within the currently activated `conda` environment, and will ensure that it is integrated with `conda` so that, for example, `conda list`, will include any packages installed with `pip`.

**NOTE**: Commands like `conda update` will ignore `pip` installed packages, as it only checks `conda` `channels` for available updates, so they still need to be updated using `pip`. See this Question/Answer discussion:

[Does conda update packages from pypi installed using pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265533/does-conda-update-packages-from-pypi-installed-using-pip-install)

**NOTE:** See @kalefranz comment below regarding `conda` 4.6 experimental handling of packages.

If you're interested in creating your own `conda` package(s), take a look at this question/1st answer for a great run-down:

[How to install my own python module (package) via conda and watch its changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474575/how-to-install-my-own-python-module-package-via-conda-and-watch-its-changes)

If you simply wish to install non-`conda` packages, using `pip` is the correct, and expected, way to go.

Comment: Conda 4.6 has an experimental feature to enable interoperability with pip-installed packages. Use `conda config --set pip_interop_enabled true`. Packages that can be "managed" by conda (i.e. removed) may be updated to satisfy the current solve. Manageable packages were typically installed from wheels.  Packages that can't be managed will anchor the environment in place until they're removed by other means. An example of unmanageable packages are "editable" installs that used `pip install -e`.

Comment: "You want to use conda packages whenever they're available", how do we achieve this? can `conda` read from `setup.py` and try to install dependencies that are available and we can use `pip install .` to do the rest? Or should we just create conda metafiles for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pip install` from within `conda` environment.

Just activate your environment using:

```
$ conda activate myenvironment
```

and use `pip install .` to install your package in environment's directory.

**EDIT:** As pointed by [Chris Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54619093/10886420) in another answert, you should install pip inside the environment using

```
$ conda install pip
```

in order to register packages correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I have a `whl` file, I can use `pip install xxx.whl` to install it.

From the [documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/#installing-packages-on-a-non-networked-air-gapped-computer), `conda install` from a local file is also available, but the file should be a tarball file, i.e. `.tar.bz2` files.

`conda install /package-path/package-filename.tar.bz2` works. And if I have multiple tarballs, I can `tar` them to get a `.tar` file, then `conda install /packages-path/packages-filename.tar` installs the packages in it.